# How can I evaluate $\partial_i \partial_j (1/r)$?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, tensors

I want to show that $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\tfrac{1}{r}\right)=\tfrac{1}{r^3}\left(\tfrac{3}{r^2}x_i x_j-\delta_{ij}\right)$ where $r=\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2}$. How can I do this? May I write the left hand side as $\tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \tfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \left(\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{x_k x_k}}\right)$?

Comment: Firstly what does $x_{kk}$ mean? Secondly just try applying the chain rule. $\frac{1}{r}=\left(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2\right)^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $x_k x_k$ where $k$ is a dummy variable.

Comment: Yes I suppose that would work, for example to help you with the first derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\left(x_k x_k\right)^{-1/2}=(-\frac{1}{2})2x_k \delta_{kj}\left(x_{k'} x_{k'}\right)^{-3/2} $. I've put a different index inside the brackets to distinguish between different summations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got it now.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} (1/r)=\frac{-x_k \delta_{kj}}{(x_{k'}x_{k'})^{3/2}}=\frac{-x_j}{(x_{k'}x_{k'})^{3/2}}$

$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \frac{1}{r}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\left[\frac{-x_j}{(x_{k'}x_{k'})^{3/2}}\right]
=\lbrace\textrm{Quotient rule}\rbrace=\frac{-\delta_{ij}
(x_{k'}x_{k'})^{3/2}+3x_j x_{k'}\delta_{ik'}(x_{k'} x_{k'})^{1/2}
}{(x_{k'}x_{k'})^{3}}=\frac{1}{r^3} \left(\frac{3}{r^2}x_i x_j -\delta_{ij}\right)$.

Comment: Looks good! ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the gradient ($g$) and Jacobian ($J$) of the function ($f$) using standard vector notation. 
$$\eqalign{
  r^2 &= x\cdot x \cr
  2\,r\,dr &= 2\,x\cdot dx \cr
 dr &= \frac{x\cdot dx}{r} \cr\cr
  f &= \frac{1}{r} \cr
 df &= -\frac{dr}{r^2} = -\frac{x}{r^3}\cdot dx \cr\cr
g &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -\frac{x}{r^3} \cr\cr
dg &= \frac{3x\,dr}{r^4}-\frac{dx}{r^3} \cr
   &= \frac{3xx\cdot dx}{r^5}-\frac{dx}{r^3} \cr
   &= \frac{3xx-r^2I}{r^5}\cdot dx \cr\cr
J &= \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{3xx-r^2I}{r^5} \cr
}$$

Comment: Just a question I think I can follow all of this except why does $r^2=x\cdot x$? And is the jacobian equal to the Hessian here? Thanks